# Understanding common multiples

Tags: assessment, arithmetic

Imagine a class of students who don't know what smallest common multiples (LCMs) are, or indeed what multiples are. (Notice I said "smallest" rather than "least" so as to avoid people thinking it means multiples that are less common than others. Actual humans exist who think that.)

You tell them the **multiples** of $63$ can be found as follows:
\begin{align}
1\times63 & = 63 \\
2\times63 & = 126 \\
3\times63 & = 189 \\
4\times63 & = 252 \\
5\times63 & = 315 \\
6\times63 & = 378 \\
& \,\,\,\vdots
\end{align}
and also as follows:
$$
63 \, \overset{\text{add 63}} \longmapsto \, 126 \, \overset{\text{add 63}} \longmapsto \, 189  \, \overset{\text{add 63}} \longmapsto \, 252 \, \overset{\text{add 63}} \longmapsto \, 315 \, \overset{\text{add 63}} \longmapsto \, 378 \, \overset{\text{add 63}} \longmapsto  \,\cdots
$$
Now do this with two numbers
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\text{multiples of 63:} & 63, & 126, & 189, & 252, & 315, & 378, & \ldots\ldots \\[4pt]
\text{multiples of 77:} & 77, & 154, & 231, & 308, & 385, & 462, & \ldots\ldots
\end{array}
$$
Not ask the class to (silently) **vote** "yes" or "no" on the answer to the following question:

**Might these two sequences of multiples go on forever without ever having any numbers is common, or if not these two, might that happen with some other pair of numbers? Yes or no.**

(By "silently" I mean they share no information before casting votes.)

Has anyone done this, perhaps with a fairly large number of students? What were the results?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks the reader to do novel research in the field of teaching and learning.

Comment: I actually use this method to find a LCM sometimes when I suspect I don't have to carry it out far and I've also occasionally used it in class lectures (this being before May 2005). I'm pretty sure that I've also used this method two or three times in some published day-job stuff I do but which I'm not officially credited for in the publications (solutions to high stakes college/professional admission tests), when it seemed best to me to give a "low-mathy approach" to solving a low-level problem (in contrast to a "high-mathy approach" in which the idea of prime-factorization is trotted out).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro : Although I understand what you mean by "this method", I wasn't actually trying to ask about a particular method, but rather about the extent to which students will understand a particular point.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins : There is also the possibility that someone has already done this.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins : I have rephrased the question so that it asks whether this has been done rather than suggesting that someone should do it.

Comment: *I wasn't actually trying to ask about a particular method, but rather about the extent to which students will understand a particular point.* --- My reading of your question was that you wanted to know any "measurable outcomes" of doing this, not whether anyone does it. My comment was only intended as a FYI remark (and yes, I know SE policy discourages these) of possible interest to you or others. Incidentally (meaning, here comes another FYI remark), it occurs to me that the method you describe is somewhat analogous to adding by counting on your fingers, something I also occasionally do.

Comment: Your series contain up to six elements. I'd advise you to go up to eight. In that way, you can show that adding just one can give an answer.

Comment: This is an interesting question, even with students who have heard of least common multipliers, and could be posed with a student response system and, if necessary, then follow up with a discussion. Or used as a question is an oral exam, or a written exam while asking for why.

Comment: @Dominique : I don't understand your comment. Where you say "can give an answer", does that mean it can identify the l.c.m.? If so, that would give away the answer to the yes/no question. However, eight is not enough for that: you need nine multiple of $77$ and $11$ mutliples of $63$ to get to the l.c.m.

Comment: I think I would precede this whole thing by asking students to write down examples of _multiples_ of $60$. I suspect some of them would write $2,3,5,$ etc. But when they see what some of their classmates write, then the confusion might be cleared up.

Comment: I think your point is that it is not obvious to many students that there is even *one* common multiple of a pair of numbers.  When teaching future elementary school teachers I found this to be the case:  when questioned no one in the class independently realized that the product of the two numbers would always get the job done.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I was talking about the $77$ list: the ninth entry equals the least common multiple of $63$ and $77$ :-)

Comment: @Dominique : And therefore that would be a spoiler, to be avoided. I am obviously trying to avoid giving away the fact that there must be some multiple that they have in common. At least it should be obvious if you read the bold-faced question to which a yes or no answer is to be sought from each student.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins : How sure are you of the novelty of the research? Notice Steven Gubkin's comment saying he has some experience with this.

Comment: @StevenGubkin Did you also try the exercise with a class of future mathematicians, scientists, and/or engineers?

Comment: @shoover No, I never had the opportunity to do so.  I did teach our intro number theory class a few times, but we start off above this level.

Answer (score 1):

I think you make it more difficult for students by introducing the "multiples" not as multiples, but by continual adding, also since 77*63 is an easy solution you are not going in the direction of LCM

Comment: Well, after they figure out 77*63, you can ask whether it is the *first* number in both sequences and then *when* (for what $a,b$) the product is the first number in both sequences, and so on, so you *are* going in the direction of the LCM. Also, multiplication by an integer *is* addition in disguise. So mathematically the approach is sound, and what will happen in the classroom if you try it is exactly the question. We can speculate, but I would just experiment if I had school kids at my disposal. As it is, I'm now teaching advanced graduate analysis, though I can try to translate :-)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what this answer says. What does "not going in the direction of LCM" mean? Obviously those who answer "yes" to the question I posed will not have noticed that $77\times63$ is a multiple that they both have in common. But what is this thing called "going in the direction of LCM" that you say I'm not doing? Is "going in the direction of LCM supposed to be a good thing or a bad thing in your view? And what is $77\times63$ supposed to be a solution to? It is not the LCM of $77$ and $63$, since that is $693.$

Comment: Last time I taught this I told them FIRST that multiples of (e.g.) $12$ are numbers you get by multiplying an integer by $12,$, thus
$$
\begin{align}
1\times12 & = 12 \\ 2\times12&=24 \\ 3\times12 & =36 \\ 4\times12 & = 48 \\ 5\times12 & = 60 \\ & \,\,\, \vdots
\end{align}
$$
THEN I pointed out that you get add $12$ to each to get the next. What I had in mind here is what happens after that: Do they realize that in every such case the two sequences must intersect each other? (I still haven't figured out what you mean by "going in the direction of LCM.")

Comment: Since 77*63 is not LCM but is too easy to guess  your question does not help to find LCM. Also pointing out the adding obscures  problem of multiples or common multiples.

Comment: @trula You've said at least twice that it's easy to see that 77*63 is a common multiple, but as Steven Gubkin says in his comment, this may not be the case.

Comment: @trula Why are you so concerned about whether my question helps people find the LCM? Did you read my posted question above?

Comment: Sorry, I did not want to criticise. I looked  to much for the heading "understanding LCM"

Comment: Here is the source of confusion:  Your title is "Understanding LCMs", but what you're actually discussing is the existence of common multiples altogether without the focus on LEAST.  I suggest you edit the title to remove reference to least/smallest.